# Подключение к API DigitalOcean с помощью Python

Tags: python, api, digitalocean

Пытаюсь подключиться с помощью Python к базе данных Postgres, развернутой на облаке DigitalOcean.

```
import json
import requests


api_token = ''
api_url_base = 'https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(api_token)}
```

Выдает ошибку 401.
Может быть, проблема в том, что идет бесплатный тестовый 3-х месячный период облачного сервиса?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401

Comment: Заработало само. Извините

Comment: Удивительно, а с вашей стороны ничего не менялось?

Comment: Нет. Возможно период тестоый завершился на дижиталокеан. Интересно, теперь можно все проекты просматривать через API и базы данных в том числе или ограничены возможности у API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import getpass
import requests
import json

from SimpleQIWI import *

token = "..........."         
phone = "+79........"

api = QApi(token=token, phone=phone)


# Используйте api.full_balance чтобы получить больше информации о кошельках. 
# {'serviceName': 'payment-history', 'errorCode': 'auth.forbidden', 'description': 'Access denied', 'userMessage': 'Access denied', 'dateTime': '2020-11-11', 'traceId': ''} 


print(api.balance)
```